# Concatenating to a large TextField

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.8

I'm dealing with a system that performs logging to a single `TextField` attribute of a model.

```
class A(models.Model):
    log = models.TextField()
    message = models.CharField()

    def update(self, log=None, message=None)
        if log is not None:
            # Reading self.log is slow.
            self.log = self.log + log  
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message
        self.save()
```

This log can become very large, and therefore the action of continuously logging (appending to it) can become quite slow as Django has to continuously read the large log field from the database and save it.

```
    a = A.objects.first() 
    a.update(log="More logging")
```

`Update` can be changed to use Django's pure database acting function `Concat`.

```
from django.db.models.function import Concat
from django.db.models import Value

def update(self, log=None, message=None)
    if log is not None:
        a.log = Concat('log', Value('More logging'))
    if message is not None:
        self.message = message
    self.save()
```

`a.log` is left as a `Concat` object and any subsequent uses of `a.log` will receive the `Concat` object instead of the original string. That means any later updates will result in more of the original concatenation:

```
a = A.objects.first()
a.update(log='More logging') # a.log = "<Original>More Logging"
a.update(message="New Message") # a.log = "<Original>More LoggingMore Logging"
```

The plan after using `F` objects or things like `Concat` is to re-read them from database. I'd rather it not be left to the caller to have to make sure the re-read is done and instead do it within the method. I thought of using `self.refresh_from_db(fields=['log'])` within `update` after the `save`, but my worry then is that doing this will cause `log` to be read from the database, defeating the entire purpose of using `Concat`. Performing some time tests indicates to me that this is actually the case as well.

How should I set `a.log` after `Concat` is used?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right approach. You don't really take advantage of the abilities of databases by doing this. Why not have a related model where each row is a separate log message?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That is the plan one day. Unfortunately this structure is what has to be dealt with for now.